# Are PV (physical volume) and partitions the same thing?

Tags: linux, partition, volume

If I call

```
fdisk /dev/sda
```

it names `/dev/sda` a disk, and `dev/sda1` a partition.

On the other hand, if I call

`pvdisplay`

then `/dev/sda2/` is a `PV name`.

Are `PV` and `partition` synonyms ? If not, what are the differences between the two ?

context: I want to resize a partition. I wonder if pvresize is the command to use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Are PV and partition synonyms ?

No.

A PV is a block device used by LVM to store data. In your case that is a partition, but it doesn't have to be, it could be a complete drive, it could be a raid array.

> I want to resize a partition. I wonder if pvresize is the command to use.

In general resizing a partition has two steps, resizing the partition itself and resizing whatever is stored on that partition. So if you have a partition containing a LVM PV you have to resize both the partition itself and the PV.

Order matters, if you are making a partition larger, you first expand the partition itself, then you use `pvresize` to expand the PV to use the new larger partition.

OTOH if you are making the partition smaller, you must first shrink the PV using `pvresize` before you shrink the partition itself.

Answer (score 3):

They are not synonyms.  Sometimes they are the same, but not always.

The Logical Volume Manager has a simple view of its world:  It builds logical volumes out of the space it has available in volume groups.  Volume groups are chunks of storage provided by lower levels, LVM doesn't care from where.

The lower level is most commonly a disk driver providing a partition, but could be a whole device, a RAID system (or partition therein) or anything else that supplies a chunk of blocks upwards.

As an example, one of my volume groups is based on the PV `/dev/md0`  However `/dev/md0` is a RAID5 system which is built from four whole disks (eg `/dev/sda`) and one partition (`/dev/sdb3`).  LVM doesn't care, it just talks to the md driver and calls it a "Physical Volume".

Comment: Thx ! To make sure I follow. In my case, the PV ```/dev/sda2``` is built on top of the partition ```/dev/sda2```. In other setting, there could be a PV ```dev/mypv``` built on top of two (or more) partition, say for example ```/dev/sda1``` and ```dev/sdb``` >

Comment: Roughly, yes.  In your case I'd not mess about trying to extend the partition, but create a new one (which will show up as a new PV) and add it to you r volume group.

Comment: A PV always sits on top of one underlying block device, but that underlying block device may not be a partition. So a PV would not sit directly on top of two paritions, but it might sit on top of a raid array and the raid array in turn might sit on top of two or more paritions (hopefully on different drives).

Answer (score 2):

An attempt at definitions with explanations

**Physical media**

- A disk is a physical device. One disk can contain zero or more partitions.
- A partition is a slice or segment of a disk. Each partition can contain a filesystem or other structured data such as swap space or an LVM PV (Physical Volume). A partition is the smallest allocatable unit on a disk: you cannot use one partition for multiple purposes.

  ```
  Physical disk
  +-------------------+
  | Partition table   |
  +-------------------+
  | Partition 1       |
  | "filesystem"      |
  +-------------------+
  | Partition 2       |
  | "PV"              |
  +-------------------+
  | Partition 3       |
  | "swap"            |
  +-------------------+
  ```

  An example of a physical disk with three partitions: a filesystem, an LVM PV, and swap.

**Logical volume management (LVM)**

- a Physical Volume (PV) is the base layer within LVM. a PV can be assigned to an entire disk or to a partition on a disk
- a Volume Group (VG) can span one or more PVs. Each VG can contain zero or more LVM LVs (Logical Volumes).
- a Logical Volume (LV) is equivalent to a physical partition: it is the smallest allocatable unit in a VG. Each LV can contain structured or unstructured data, for example, a filesystem or swap space. LVs can be easily resized larger and smaller, but note that the structured information inside them may not be so easily resized.

  ```
  Volume Group             Also Volume Group
  +-------------------+    +-------------------+
  | +---------------+ |    | +---------------+ |
  | | PV            | |    | | LV            | |
  | |               | |    | | "filesystem"  | |
  | +---------------+ |    | |               | |
  |                   |    | |               | |
  | +---------------+ |    | +---------------+ |
  | | PV            | |    |                   |
  | |               | |    |                   |
  | +---------------+ |    |                   |
  +-------------------+    +-------------------+
  ```

  An example of an LVM VG. First shown by physical assignment from disk partitions (each partition containing a PV), and then shown as a container of LVs. Notice that an LV does not need to be constrained in size to any PV. That's why it's *Logical* Volume Management.

When you resize a partition you are changing the physical allocation of space (for structured data) on a disk. When you resize an LV you are changing the logical allocation on a disk (for structured data).

If you resize either a partition or an LV to make it larger you must also remember to resize its structured data (filesystem, swap, etc.). If you resize either a partition or an LV to make it smaller you must *first remember to reduce the size of its structured data*, as otherwise you will end up truncating the data and corrupting its contents.

Comment: Remember that XFS filesystems cannot be shrunk.  It's a backup-recreate-restore operation.

Comment: @Martin indeed, "_the structured information inside them may not be so easily resized_"